# A problem of probabilities, calculation of 2 events

Tags: probability, self-study

I have this problem: A student must choose exactly two out of three electives: art, French, and mathematics. He chooses art with probability 5/8, French with probability 5/8, and art and French together with probability 1/4. What is the probability that he chooses mathematics? What is the probability that he chooses either art or French?

Now my rationale was this:

p(A and F)+p(F and M)+p(A and M)=1 something has to happen.
1/4+p(F and M)+p(A and M)=1

p(F and M)+p(A and M)=3/4

p(M)=p(F and M)+p(A and M)

p(M)=3/4

But how do I get p(A) or p(F).

Thanks.

Comment: If this is homework or self-study, please add the appropriate tag - you'll still get help working towards the answer (to improve your understanding), just not have the answer handed to you.

Comment: If he chooses art together with French, does he choose math?  If he doesn't choose art together with French, does he choose math?  If he chooses math, does he also choose either art or French?

Comment: Tag added, no if he chooses A and F there is no way to choose M, and yes if he does not choose F and A, then he must choose M, yes choosing M keeps you from choosing both A or F

Answer (score 1):

You can directly solve for the smaller problem: $P(A \cup F) = P(A) + P(F) - P(A\cap F) = \frac{5}{8} + \frac{5}{8} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{8}{8} = 1$! Which also makes logical sense, since he has to pick two of three electives.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, this is for p(A or F),like p(A) or p(F), and what about M is my answer correct? :)

Comment: Yes, your answer for M is correct. p(A) or p(F) is not an event, you do math operations on probabilities, logic/set operations on events, so the event for choosing art or french is $A\cup B$

Comment: With respect to M; since he must choose math if he doesn't choose A & F, p(Math) = 1 - P(A&F), which is given in the problem statement.  p(A or F) means probability of either A or F or both, which would be written, in set notation, as in the answer.